# ASP.NET Validation errors with subclassed models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model called Job which has a required field, here it is for simplicity:

```
public class Job
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Insured Name is required.")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Insured Name cannot be longer than 100 characters.")]
    [DisplayName("Insured Name")]
    public string InsuredName { get; set; }
}
```

I now need to have a type of job called a Private Job which has identical fields, and is mapped to the same database table, except I'm trying to change the validation messages for a bunch of fields.  Ie, Insured Name becomes Client Name.

I thought I could do this by subclassing, so I created as an example:

```
[NotMapped]
public class PrivateJobDTO : Job
{   
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Client Name is required.")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Client Name cannot be longer than 100 characters.")]
    [DisplayName("Client Name")]
    new public string  InsuredName { get; set; }

}
```

When I pass a PrivateJobDTO to my viewmodel, I still get the validation error message that "Insured Name is required", whereas I was expecting to see "Client Name is required"

What am I doing wrong? (and is this the right approach)

Comment: How do you pass PrivateJobDTO instance ? Would you share it too ?

Comment: You don't need to inherit the Model, view model can be separate from data model as long as you are using correct bind prefix required for model binding.

Comment: how are you passing the `PrivateJobDTO` object to the model?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the problem was that I was passing the base class to the model, not the subclass!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, it showed me that I was passing the base class to the model, not the sub class, silly mistake.